# Downloading Kindle for Android tablet

Tags: google-play-store

I got Android tablet with the latest OS (4.0). I am trying to install Amazon Kindle app on it. I access the Google market via browser and select install. Then it is saying it will be downloaded shortly, but nothing happens. What is the problem? For some unknown reason I can't connect to google market via app on the Android tablet itself (failed connection). Before that I was able to download and install apps on tablet. The tablet: Zenithink ZT ICS. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: So can you not download *any* apps from the Play Store? It sounds like you have a bigger issue than just being unable to install Kindle.

Comment: I just replaced the amazon-kindle tag (as it refers to the kindle tablet, not the app) by the playstore tag. As the playstore app on your tablet cannot connect to the playstore website, I'd say all installations via the playstore will fail -- regardless of the app to be installed: No connection, no data transfer, so no install. Your real problem is getting the playstore app to work. This would solve your described issue implicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to install it directly from this page - http://www.1mobile.com/kindle-13239.html

However, be warned that due to certain geographical restrictions, the app may NOT work as intended if not supported.

Re: your market app not connecting - can you browse the net or connect other apps? Can you sync your Google account on your device? What tablet do you have?

Comment: I can browse the Internet. I can connect to gmail.

Comment: Before you start the Play Store app, try signing in to Google Talk. Also, make sure you're running the latest firmware from your manufacturer.

Comment: An additional note - if your app is called "Market" and not "Play Store", you need to update that app (perhaps by sideloading it). And finally, a number of ahem..."lesser known" companies have released tablets that run Android, however the official Google Play Store may not recognize the devices and as such, you may not be able to get the functionality. As an alternative, look at other Market apps like Amazon App Store and SlideME.

Comment: Yeah, for some reasons I can't connect to Google Talk. I have already posted  a new thread for that. The app is called 'Play Store'. Google Play Stores recognizes my device; you may selected it in the list of my devices.

Comment: ok, I took your advice and get the app directly via that link. It works fine now.